# Appcelerator - How to add Universal Links support in iOS9 App

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, ios-universal-links

I want to allow my users to open our app (if installed, otherwise redirect to App Store App page), whenever user clicks web url of our website.

I found that **Universal Links** is a way to go for the said requirements from iOS-9 onward. I also know the points to be covered on Web server and Apple Developer portal.

The only question is **How do I enable Associated Domains in Appcelerator Titanium app**?

Thanks in advance for any clue or help.

Answer (score 7):

We have working universal links for both ios + android on our production apps with this process (based off of [AppC Handoff Sample App](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/10/ios-handoff-sample-app/):

1) Add associated domains on Apple Dev Center to the app -> This will generate a new provisioning profile which you will want to use to build in Titanium.

2) You need to explicitly edit your Entitlments.plist file, usually this is auto generated by Ti. To get a copy of this file do the following:

```
a) Build app for device
b) Navigate to project\build\iphone
c) Find the generated Entitlments.plist file
```

3) Copy this file over to your project's root folder and add the following under the "dict" node:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated­domains</key>
<array>
  <string>applinks:www.example.com</string> 
</array>
```

This should create the necessary data to bind app to the correct website for linking.

4) Now to actually capture the deeplinking click + url you need to listen to the following event: [Ti.App.iOS.continueactivity](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS-event-continueactivity)

ex:

```
Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('continueactivity', function(e){
  //Since this event can be fired from multiple cases 
  //we need to check if it was a deeplink that fired it
  if(e.activityType === "NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb"){
    //Since it WAS from a deeplink, the event response contains some 
    //other useful data (see the docs link)
    var deepLinkURL = e.webpageURL;
    //From here you can navigate the app to a relevant page etc...
  }
};
```

Sadly, this functionality was broken in sdk 5.X, it was fixed here: [TIMOB-20220](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20220) (a one liner) but it won't be included in an official .GA sdk until 5.4.0 from what I hear (which is scheduled for release in June).

If you have further questions the [Ti Slack](http://ti-slack.slack.com/) group chat is a great place to ask as well (a whole bunch of active users).

Comment: Having that I tested out the [nightly build](http://builds.appcelerator.com/#master) and it worked a treat again in iOS after 4 months with this bug. If you have no reservations against nightly builds you could just use it directly.

Comment: Thank you for your great help @Boarnoah! I will try this out soon. BTW, how can I join that Ti Slack group?

Comment: @Manaday you should be able to connect to https://ti-slack.slack.com/ and create  a Slack account.

Comment: it requires mail invite. Could you please help me to get the invite on m.k.mavani[at]gmail.com?

Comment: @Boarnoah I have tried steps given by you: Enabled Associated Domains in App ID and created new adhoc certificate for the same. I also have added Entitlements.plist in my project. But as soon as I try to install the package on device it shows me error like "invalid entitlements". As soon as I disable Associated Domains and create new certificate for the app id, the app gets installed. Can you guide me here what can I do to install the adhoc package on my device..?

Comment: @Manaday you are right there does appear to be an invite step: http://tislack.org/signup (this should send an email invite I'm told).

Comment: @Mobihunterz I've personally not run into an invalid entitlements issue trying out this procedure, just in case can you verify that your entitlements data match this: (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20220?focusedCommentId=381135&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-381135) Mr Ricardo is basing his steps over the sample app we sent to him privately earlier on. Also double check that your provisioning profile is indeed updated and of course clean the project. Good luck